# How to get sum of the Y position of instantiated objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to make my finish line to be proportional as objects so when there is Y position of last object is on -50 I want to finish line be at -55 so when user finish the game he goes to next level.

For now i have gameobject on screen and i need to manually move the object.

I am making obstacles with this code:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Instantiate(obstacles[0], new Vector3(obstacles[0].transform.position.x, startSpawn, obstacles[0].transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
        startSpawn -= deltaY;
    }
```

So my question is how i can read the Y of the last object instantiated and add few numbers to instantiate finish like right after the last object is passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a field that tracks the last object created:

```
public GameObject lastObjectCreated;
```

Assign to it each iteration of the instantiation loop (the assignment of the last iteration will be remembered):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    lastObjectCreated = Instantiate(obstacles[0], new Vector3(obstacles[0].transform.position.x, startSpawn, obstacles[0].transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
    startSpawn -= deltaY;
}
```

When you want to read its `y` position, read `lastObjectCreated.transform.position.y`:

```
float yPosition = lastObjectCreated.transform.position.y;
```

Comment: What i need to assign to inspector for lastObjectCreated? My obstacles or it can be none?

Comment: @NoviKorisnikk You might want to assign it something just to avoid null reference errors, but just make sure you instantiate the objects before you check the y position.